# Haswell power efficiency compared to Ivy and Sandy

Tags: laptop, cpu, haswell

After reading a few reviews about the Haswell CPU series, I concluded that upgrading from Ivy or Sandy bridge might not be worth it considering the limited power gain. However Intel does advertise that the power efficiency has increased dramatically compared to the previous editions of CPUs.

I'm wondering how this translates to practical usage as there is little  I can find about that. **How does a notebook equiped with a Hasswell CPU perform in real life compared to its predecesor when it comes to power usage?** Are we talking a few minutes of extra battery time per hour (during normal usage) or are there significant gains?

I do not wish to debate, I prefer facts and numbers.

Comment: One problem is that improving CPU energy efficiency runs into a variant of Amdahl's Law. The energy consumption of the display, networking, disk, etc. becomes a larger fraction of the total energy consumption. If the energy efficiency of these other components is not improved, the benefit of improved CPU efficiency will become increasingly less significant.

Comment: Don't. Haswell processors eat even more power for their built-in FIVR module.